# Converting SELECT DISTINCT ON queries from Postgresql to MySQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, select, group-by, distinct

I've been using **PostgreSQL** and now migrating to **MySQL**.

In my queries, I'm using **PostgreSQL**'s `SELECT DISTINCT ON (col1, col2, col3)`, I was wondering if there is any counterpart of this statement in **MySQL**.

Comment: You can try 
`Select DISTINCT concat(col1,col2,col3) from table ` if you need the combination of the three to be distinct

Comment: I guess in MySQL you need to use a "partial" `group by` on those three columns (which would not be allowed in any other DBMS) and live with the fact that you get unpredictable values for the non-distinct columns.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

There's not an exact equivalent to convert a Postgresql query that makes use of SELECT DISTINCT ON to MySQL.

**Postgresql SELECT DISTINCT ON**

In Postgresql, the following query will eliminate all rows where the expressions `(col1, col2, col3)` match, and it will only keep the "first col4, col5 row" for each set of matched rows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (col1, col2, col3) col4, col5
FROM tablename
```

So if your table is like this:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5
--------------------------------
1    | 2    | 3    | 777  | 888
1    | 2    | 3    | 888  | 999
3    | 3    | 3    | 555  | 555
```

our query will keep just one row for (1,2,3) and one row for (3,3,3). The resulting rows will then be:

```
col4 | col5
-----------
777  | 888
555  | 555
```

please notice that the "first row" of each set is unpredictable, our fist row might be (888, 999) as well unless we specify an ORDER BY:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (col1, col2, col3) col4, col5
FROM tablename
ORDER BY col1, col2, col3, col4
```

(the DISTINCT on expressions must match the leftmost ORDER BY expressions, but the ORDER BY can contain additional expressions).

**MySQL extension to GROUP BY**

MySQL extends the use of [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html) so that we can select nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. Whenever we select nonaggregated columns the server is free to choose any value from each group from that column, so the resulting values will be indetermined.

So this Postgresql query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (col1, col2, col3) col4, col5
FROM tablename
```

can be considered equivalent to this MySQL query:

```
SELECT col4, col5
FROM tablename
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
```

both Postgresql and MySQL will return the "First row" for each (col1, col2, col3), and in both cases the row returned is unpredictable because we didn't specify and order by clause.

A lot of people would be very tempted to convert this Postgresql query with an ORDER BY:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (col1, col2, col3) col4, col5
FROM tablename
ORDER BY col1, col2, col3, col4
```

with this one:

```
SELECT col4, col5
FROM (
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
  FROM tablename
  ORDER BY col1, col2, col3, col4
) s
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
```

the idea here is to apply an ORDER BY to a subquery so that when MySQL groups by col1, col2, col3 it will keep the first encountered value for col4 and col5. **The idea is good, but it's wrong!** MySQL is free to choose any value for col4 and col5, and we don't know which are the first values encountered, it depends on the optimizer. So I would correct it to this:

```
SELECT t1.col4, t1.col5
FROM tablename t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT col1, col2, col3, MIN(col4) as m_col4
                              FROM tablename
                              GROUP BY col1, col2, col3) s
     ON t1.col1=s.col1
        AND t1.col2=s.col2
        AND t1.col3=s.col3
        AND t1.col4=s.m_col4
GROUP BY
  t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, t1.col4
```

but this is starting to get more complicated.

**Conclusion**

As a general rule, there's not an exact way to convert a Postgresql query to a MySQL query, but there are a lot of workarounds, the resulting query might be as simple as the original one or it might become very complicated, but it depends on the query itself.

Comment: Also because more modern MySQL/MariaDB servers are going to follow the SQL standard more most likely the `ORDER BY` in the subquery will also can/will be [ignored](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/) without changing the subqeury resultset with `LIMIT` meaning the results can change upgrading from a older MySQL version to a more modern one.

Comment: "As a general rule, there's not an exact way to convert a Postgresql query to a MySQL query, but there are a lot of workarounds" Indeed i find the MySQL's [SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(.... ORDER BY ....), ..)](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ioddCbTbeHgTKcCeHHzLpL/0) method the most easy or best native method to implemented `DISTINCT ON (col1, col2, col3), *` syntax ... Also because of the other comment where MariaDB/MySQL could ignore `ORDER BY` in subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery to determine the order, and an outer query to group them.

Like @a_horse_with_no_name points out, this works because MySQL allows partial `group by`, unlike other DBMSs.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE customer_order
    (`customer` varchar(5), `item` varchar(6), `date` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO customer_order
    (`customer`, `item`, `date`)
VALUES
    ('alice', 'widget', '2000-01-05 00:00:00'),
    ('bob', 'widget', '2000-01-02 00:00:00'),
    ('alice', 'widget', '2000-01-01 00:00:00'),
    ('alice', 'wodget', '2000-01-06 00:00:00')
;
```

Query for each customer's first order:

```
select *
from
  (select customer, item, date
  from customer_order
  order by date) c
group by customer
```

Result:

```
| CUSTOMER |   ITEM |                           DATE |
|----------|--------|--------------------------------|
|    alice | widget | January, 01 2000 00:00:00+0000 |
|      bob | widget | January, 02 2000 00:00:00+0000 |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6cbbe/1

Comment: Also because more modern MySQL/MariaDB servers are going to follow the SQL standard more most likely the `ORDER BY` in the subquery will also can/will be [ignored](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/) without changing the subqeury resultset with `LIMIT` meaning the results can change upgrading from a older MySQL version to a more modern one.

Comment: If the above query is not working, try this: SELECT customer,
       min(date) AS max_date
FROM customer_order
GROUP BY customer;

Answer (score 0):

if with DISTINCT ON  you want to join last (or some specific) record from one-to-many relation, you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM customer c LEFT JOIN purchase p 
ON (SELECT purchaseID FROM purchase WHERE customerID = c.customerID ORDER BY Purchase_Date DESC LIMIT 1) = purchaseID
```

Answer (score -6):

> you should migrate to **PDO** or **MSYQLI**  instead of **MYSQL**  as its already deprecated.

about your question you can do

```
   SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, col3
```

or

```
    SELECT col1, col2, col3
    ........

    GROUP BY col1 --//--- or whatever column you want to be distinct
```

Answer (score -6):

You can't select distinct values from multiple columns. while selecting use query like this

```
select distinct col1, col2 from table
```