# Convert Postgres query with distinct on to MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a table **users**:

[image: users]

Where **id** is a primary key.

I want to select all columns, but all usernames should be unique. I don't care which ids will be in an expected result, but anyway I need them. For that I use the following query in Posgres 10:

`select distinct on (username) * from users;`

That gives me the result I want:

[image]

How can I achieve the same, but using MySQL query?

Comment: Maybe this was asked before, but I didn't find the similar problem. It would be very helpful if you could share a link if my question is a duplicate instead of simply downwoting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting SELECT DISTINCT ON queries from Postgresql to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673457/converting-select-distinct-on-queries-from-postgresql-to-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query doesn't make sense in Postgres because it lacks an `order by`.  For this query:

```
select distinct on (username) u.*
from users u
order by username, id desc;
```

You can write this as:

```
select u.*
from users u
where u.id = (select max(u2.id) from users u2 where u2.username = u.username);
```

Assuming `id` is unique, this will return one row per username.

Comment: Yep, **id** is a primary key in my case. Will edit the question. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the conversion of that
`SELECT id, username FROM users group by id`

You can find more info on this link:[Converting SELECT DISTINCT ON queries from Postgresql to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673457/converting-select-distinct-on-queries-from-postgresql-to-mysql)

Extra Note: You can use this http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0bd1a2/1 to test your SQL which maybe helpful for you in converting Postgres to SQL

Comment: This query returns result with only **username** column, but I need **id** as well

Comment: ERROR:  column "users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT id, username FROM users group by username;

Comment: Actually  **id** is primary key

Comment: I want to say use this `SELECT id, username
FROM users;
WHERE (SELECT DISTINCT(id) From users)` however this code may give you some other errors as I do not how your database is set up from your case. I still think a group by would be fitting  to use.