# Django, group by one field, only take the latest / max of each group and get back the ORM objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

I have the following Django (3.0) ORM model:

```
class Portfolio(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to group them by the `code` field and for each code only take the portfolio that has the max `date`

I know I can use the following query:

```
Portfolio.objects.values('code').annotate(latest=Max('date'))
```

But it has three problems:

1. It gives me only the `code` and `latest` fields, so I lose the other fields
2. It gives back a dictionary, while I want a list of actual `Portfolio` objects
3. `Max` works because `date` is a `DateField`. It would also work on other numeric field types, but what if I want to order the records by the value of a CharField (lexicographic order), for instance `name` and take the first record for each group?

So, to sum up, my question: **How do I use Django ORM to retrieve a list of ORM Objects grouped by one or more fields and have back only the first record of each group given an arbitrary "order by" clause?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Getting first / last value from group(s)*** is exactly what **DISTINCT ON with ORDER BY** SQL clause [can be used for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9795768/12520350) (*but afaik **only in Postgresql**. In MySQL just `DISTINCT`, no `ON`, so  - [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17673457/12520350)(directly), SQLite also does not support `DISTINCT ON`, just `DISTINCT`. To signify this, in Django [positional arguments to `.distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) can be passed only in Postgresql*).

In Django we can do this with *QuerySet* like this:

```
Portfolio.objects.order_by().order_by(
    'code', # first, cause we want to group by this value
    '-created' # descending order, latest / max will be first
).distinct('code')
```

Here we use empty `.order_by()` call to *__clear all ordering already present __* on *QuerySet* (added or default) to make sure only required ordering is applied with next `.order_by(...)` for grouping to work correctly.

---

General way to use it:

- Starting *QuerySet* with filters applied - `q = SomeModel.objects.filter(col1__gt=2)`
- clear ordering that is already set on the *QuerySet* - `q.order_by()`
- add ordering with the grouping columns first (used in `distinct` later) with additional columns after - `q.order_by('col1', '-col2', '-col3', '-date1')`

  Here:

  - *'col1', 'col2', 'col3'* - are columns / fields we want to `GROUP BY` (for grouping)
  - *'col1', '-col2', '-col3'* - same columns we want to group by, but with the ordering we want to use for grouping (crucial for all sub-groups - all columns in groups list *except the first one* - for them it will affect the resulted rows being fetched from groups - *'first'* or *'last'*; for the first column it will not affect result rows, only result ordering)
  - *'-date1'* - any additional ordering columns of our choice to order final group rows
- Finally add `.distinct()` clause with the fields we choose for grouping as arguments, in the same order as in `.order_by()` clause - `q.distinct('col1', 'col2', 'col3')`

Comment: Trying to use `DISTINCT ON` with SQLite backend will trigger backend to raise `NotSupportedError`.

Comment: In MySQL/Maria too. I think it only works on Postgres