# get distinct "title" in mysql in django

Tags: mysql, django

I have used django to develop a web app.
I want to get the distinct "title" form the queryset get by filter.

But I use mysql so could not pass "title" to distict.
How could I filter the queryset with the distinct "title"?

```
query_set = CourseInfo.objects.filter(discipline_id=id).distinct('title')

return render(request, 'main.html',
                     context={'query_set':query_set})
```

I get error for this in mysql as it may only used in postgresql
`

Answer (score 0):

It will give you distinct titles:

```
titles = CourseInfo.objects.filter(
    discipline_id=id
).order_by('title').values('title').distinct()
```

***Note:***
there is no such thing called `SELECT DISTINCT ON` in MySQL.
You can only use it in Postgresql but maybe `GROUP BY` helps you for converting `SELECT DISTINCT ON` query to MySQL query.
Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673457/converting-select-distinct-on-queries-from-postgresql-to-mysql) then you kinda can convert this query to MySQL query.