# SQLalchemy ignoring some columns while dedupping

Tags: python, sql, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a User table that has many columns in it. While I query this table, I want to ignore some columns for dedupliation.

For example, a row must be treated as duplicate, when all of the columns are the same, but address and city columns have different value.

My query looks like below, but currently it keeps returning that rows that must be treated as duplicate and filtered out

```
all_columns = [column for column in User.__table__.columns if column.name not in UserExceptions.nondeduped_columns]


data = (
    User.query.filter(User.company_id == company_id)
    .join(
        Team,
        Team.id == Team.team_id
    ),
)
.distinct(*all_columns)
.all()
)
```

I have tried the query above.

Comment: For me this code emits a warning: "SADeprecationWarning: DISTINCT ON is currently supported only by the PostgreSQL dialect.  Use of DISTINCT ON for other backends is currently silently ignored, however this usage is deprecated, and will raise CompileError in a future release for all backends that do not support this syntax."

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17673457/5320906) answer your question?