# SQL retrieve recent record

Tags: sql

I want to retrieve TOPIC 1 SCORES with the most recent score (excluding null) (sorted by date) for each detailsID, (there are only detailsID 2 and 3 here, therefore only two results should return)

Comment: It does not return ***per `detailsID`*** because this is not what you put in your `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I select rows with most recent timestamp for each key value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327043/how-can-i-select-rows-with-most-recent-timestamp-for-each-key-value)

Answer (score 0):

What about getting rid of `Topic 1 Scores` in `GROUP BY`detailsID`,`Topic 1 Scores ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server:

```
SELECT  
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY detailsID ORDER BY Date DESC) AS RowNumber,
    detailsID, Date, Topic 1 Scores
FROM 
    Information.scores
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to get the max and then join to it.

```
SELECT a.detailsID,`Topic 1 Scores`, a.Date 
FROM Information.scores AS a
JOIN (SELECT detailsID, MAX(Date) "MaxDate"
      FROM Information.scores
      WHERE `Topic 1 Scores` IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY detailsID) Maxes
ON a.detailsID = Maxes.detailsID
   AND a.Date = Maxes.MaxDate
WHERE `Topic 1 Scores` IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: '2','100','26/09/2017'
'2','0','26/09/2017'
'2','45','26/09/2017'
'3','30','25/09/2017'
This is returned instead,

Comment: So you have ties in the Date per detailsID?  Do you have any other IDs or a DateTime?

Comment: @LottieT Please post a sample of your data with all of the columns you have.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing

```
SELECT detailsID,`Topic 1 Scores`, MAX(Date) as "Date" GROUP BY "Date"
```

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY "Date"' at line 1

Comment: You need to add which table its selecting from (FROM tablename)