# Redshift Merge rows and conflict-resolve by timestamp

Tags: amazon-redshift

This is unlike the [selecting row with latest timestamp question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327043/how-can-i-select-rows-with-most-recent-timestamp-for-each-key-value) and is **specific to Redshift**

I want to allow users to update parts of a (staging) table row at different points in time *while avoiding invoking `UPDATE` statements*. This is done by an append-only approach where we keep adding rows where only the unique id and a timestamp is mandatory and the other columns may or may not have a value provided.

Question:

Given a table where apart from "primary key" (not truely enforced) and a timestamp column, all other columns in that table are **nullable**, how do I merge all rows that have the same primary key into one row **by picking the most recent non-null value for each nullable columns**, if one such non-null value exists.

Example:

```
|id|timestamp|status|stringcol|numcol|
|1 |456      |begin |         |      |
|1 |460      |      |         |  2   |
|2 |523      |      |  foo    |      |
|1 |599      |mid   |  blah   |      |
|2 |624      |begin |         |      |
|1 |721      |done  |         |  60  |
```

should produce

```
|id|timestamp|status|stringcol|numcol|
|2 |624      |begin |  foo    |      |
|1 |721      |done  |  blah   |  60  |
```

Comment: There is a `DISTINCT ON` feature in PostgreSQL that does exactly this! However, it is not available in Amazon Redshift. Here is something that claims to mimic that behaviour: [DISTINCT ON like functionality for Redshift](https://gist.github.com/jmindek/62c50dd766556b7b16d6)

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using Redshift's `LISTAGG` function combined with `SPLIT_PART` function.

- `LISTAGG` [concatenates all values in a group into a single string](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html), optionally allow you to order to contatenation and provide a delimiter.
- `SPLIT_PART` [splits a string by a delimiter and returns the chosen part](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html)

Using the above example 5-column table, you would need something like this:

```
SELECT id, 
       MAX(last_updated),
       SPLIT_PART(LISTAGG(status, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY last_updated DESC), ',', 1),
       SPLIT_PART(LISTAGG(stringcol, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY last_updated DESC), ',', 1),
       SPLIT_PART(LISTAGG(numcol, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY last_updated DESC), ',', 1)
FROM table
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: The above query needs `last_updated` be part of group by too

Comment: Thanks @mdem7 it was a typo but actually on the last_updated instead of the `group by`